# Placing an object in the chart to mouse coordinates using event.pageX

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I struggle with positioning an object to the mouse coordinates in a d3 chart I have.

```
var svg = d3.select(#myChart).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const tl = svg.append('line').attr("style", "position: absolute;");

 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                 tl.attr('stroke', 'black')
                .attr('x1', (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px" )
                .attr('x2',(d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
                .attr('y1', 0 )
                .attr('y2', height );

        })
```

When the chart is aligned to the left, I can see the line being like 50px to the left of the mouse (as if X of mouse + 40). When the chart is positioned to the right, the line is not even visible. I would need the line to be always on the XMouse position, with 0 being constant (a vertical line).

Comment: Which version of d3.js are you using?

Comment: @Zim version v4

Comment: You have to provide the full code. The position d3.event.pageX / pageY returns the position relative to the entire document. You apply it to an element tl, which is probably translated in your code (not visible to us)

Comment: @ee2Dev The thing is, my code is to be embedded into a page which content I do not know, so I need the position to be relative to the chart itself, if possible. I updated the question with the "tl" element.

Comment: Provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve